# Git clone trying to treat a file like it's a directory?

Tags: git, ubuntu, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to clone a git repository that we are hosting on a local Ubuntu server from within Visual Studio 2019. I am able to clone other repositories from the same server but i'm getting an error with this one in particular and it makes no sense. Might be a bug, might be a configuration problem.

Here's the error log (paths edited for security reasons):

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\my_username\Documents\Projects\ProjectName'...
Warning: error opening directory '\\GitServer\Repo\ProjectName/objects/incoming-a01148/47/c4f1223ef91fff4cf45f549beff2fff5656fad/': Function not implemented
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
failed to iterate over '\\GitServer\Repo\ProjectName/objects/'
```

What makes no sense to me is that ".../objects/incoming-a01148/47/c4f1223ef91fff4cf45f549beff2fff5656fad" is a file and it looks like it's trying to iterate over it as if it's a directory?

Comment: That's in the quarantine directory, not sure what else is going on here though. Build Git from source and add some debug, perhaps.

Comment: This looks like the contents of a (hidden) `.git` directory, but exposed and not inside a `.git` subdirectory. I'd say something is not right on your `\\GitServer\Repo\ProjectName`. Are you sure that is a clonable location? Usually when cloning from a filesystem you need to add a prefix like in `file:///some/path`.

Comment: It was doing it from a normal object directory earlier, but that changed after i ran chown -R on the whole objects folder.

Comment: I should have clarified, i'm connecting from my workstation via file share. The folder "Repo" is at the root of the filesystem on the server and is shared. Also connecting from a windows 10 machine.

Comment: Can you try prepending "file://" to your clone URL (and try cloning from scratch into a clean directory)? Another thing to try is just using forward slashes instead of backslashes everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `file://GitServer/Repo/ProjectName` instead of `\\GitServer\Repo\ProjectName` in the clone process seems to have resolved the problem.